# Type Error occur when using StableDiffusionControlNetInpaintPipeline

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

I found an error when using StableDiffusionControlNetInpaintPipeline, I am not sure why it happen.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/background_replacement/local_tester.py", line 50, in <module>
    output = pipe(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/xl_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/xl_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/pipelines/controlnet/pipeline_controlnet_inpaint.py", line 1387, in __call__
    init_latents_proper = self.scheduler.add_noise(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/xl_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_pndm.py", line 473, in add_noise
    noisy_samples = sqrt_alpha_prod * original_samples + sqrt_one_minus_alpha_prod * noise
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (512) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 3
```

And my source code just like this:

```
model_id = 'stabilityai/chilloutmix_NiPrunedFp32Fix'
controlnet_id = 'controlnet/sd-controlnet-canny'

controlnet = ControlNetModel.from_pretrained(controlnet_id)
pipe = StableDiffusionControlNetInpaintPipeline.from_pretrained(
    model_id,
    controlnet=controlnet,
).to("cuda")

...

output = pipe(
            prompt=[prompt] * 1 if prompt is not None else None,
            guidance_scale=guidance_scale,
            generator=generator,
            num_inference_steps=num_inference_steps,
            **extra_kwargs,
        )
```

Could someone help me deal with it?

I tried to change the base model, but it seems didn't work.